# How to make Git-bash command line start up with home directory?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

Git-bash.exe is installed at this location:

```
C:\Program Files\Git
```

Git-bash.exe starts up with these prompts:

```
bash: /c/Users/GodCoder/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
GodCoder / $
```

(GodCoder is just the username)
This file named, 'git-promt.sh' is definitely present at that location, still that promt!

Now, after I tried to print the current working directory which is the same directory where Git-bash is installed i.e. `C:\Program Files\Git` , it showed this:

```
GodCoder / $ pwd
/
```

Now, how to change this, default startup directory to my home directory location which is `C:\Users\GodCoder` i.e. I want `Git-hub.exe` to start up like this

```
GodCoder ~ $
```

Instead of starting up in this way

```
GodCoder / $
```

How to achieve this `GodCoder ~ $`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `git.exe` to your `path` variable?

Comment: What is `git.exe` and how to get this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, do this
Right click on the Windows shortcut that you use to launch git bash, and click Properties. Change the value of "Start In" to your desired workspace path i.e.
Replace the start in values with `"C:\Users\GodCoder"`

For more information go to this link: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775/lessons/2980038599/concepts/33417185870923 
It may help you in setting up your enviroment further and also, make sure you restart the application or even the pc and try running in admin or different user modes too!

Comment: Okay I did that but it is not working, still same prompts and same start up location

Comment: For more information go to this link: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775/lessons/2980038599/concepts/33417185870923  It may help you in setting up your enviroment further

Comment: Also, make sure you restart the application or even the pc and try running in different user modes too!

Answer (score 1):

Start your git bash with a `/dir` like this: `git-bash.exe /dir "C:\Users\GodCoder"`